# Need help to create a Do-While loop in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, azure-active-directory, do-while

I'm a fresh newbie to PowerShell and coding, but I need to make a do-while loop to achieve some tasks here.

I need to run this loop to detect if a specific user is being deleted from the Azure AD. If yes, restore the user.

I know how to list the deleted user by `get-msoluser -returnDeteltedUsers`

And I also know how to restore the user by `Restore-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "user's email"`

But I need help with this if statement. How can I ask it to return true of false whether the user is deleted or not.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Can you explain why you need a Do loop for this when it can be accomplished with a foreach loop? Are the same users being deleted over and over again? If so, what are the conditions to end the Do loop?

Comment: Sorry I didn't included everything I need in my question. Eventually I want to set up a timer in the loop as well, to run it every 30 seconds. To end the loop when it detects the user is active.

Comment: @VincentJi Although I still don't think you need to use do-while for a timer, I update my answer to implement it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @santisq, do-while does not apply to this scenario.

Just use the `foreach` loop statement directly.

```
$specificUser = "{specificUser}"

$deletedusers = get-msoluser -returndeletedusers

foreach($deleteduser in $deletedusers){
    if($specificUser -eq $deleteduser.UserPrincipalName){
        Restore-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $specificUser
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Set a timer with do-while:

```
$specificUser = "{specificUser}"

$deleteduserUPN = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$deletedusers = get-msoluser -returndeletedusers
    foreach($deleteduser in $deletedusers){
        $deleteduserUPN.Add($deleteduser.UserPrincipalName)
    }

if($specificUser -in $deleteduserUPN){
    
    do {

        Restore-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $specificUser

        start-sleep -seconds 30

        $deleteduserUPN.Clear()
        $deletedusers = get-msoluser -returndeletedusers
        foreach($deleteduser in $deletedusers){
            $deleteduserUPN.Add($deleteduser.UserPrincipalName)
        }

    } while ($specificUser -in $deleteduserUPN)
    
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, if you need to restore ALL deleted users you may remove the if condition and change `$specificUser` for `$deletedUser.userPrincipalName`. If you have a list of UPN you need to restore then you can change the if condition for `-in` instead of `-eq`.

Comment: In addition, there is no need to "check if the user was restored", if you use `Restore-MsolUser` and you don't get any error, the user was in fact restored. No need to re-check this. Also, `MSOnline` is a pretty old module. I recommend using `AzureAD` Module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0. Cheers, Santi.

Comment: Thanks Allen for the answer and all the suggestions. I haven't try it yet, but logically I believe it will do the trick. Thanks!!